If you switch jobs, can you get another FSA at the new job?
Let's say I have a job where I have contributed to an FSA. Can I switch jobs and contribute to another FSA during the window to enroll for benefits?
What happens if I maxed out the first job's FSA? What happens if I didn't?

For the part about the new company - yes, you can contribute to a new FSA, there's no relationship or dependencies between them.
